# Show/Hide does not work on Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, safari

I am trying to hide button when its clicked to prevent multiple clicks. I am using the following code

```
jQuery('#edit-next').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('#edit-next').hide();
    jQuery('#gif-loader').show();
});
```

It works on all browsers except Safari and safari on IOS devices ( works on IOS chrome ).

I am not sure what is causing the error. Using e.preventDefault(); makes show/hide work on Safari but the form is not submitted.

Also tried

```
jQuery.noConflict()(document).ready(function() {    
    jQuery('#edit-next').click(function (e) {
        document.getElementById('edit-next').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('gif-loader').style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```

And

```
jQuery.noConflict()(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#edit-next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('edit-next').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('gif-loader').style.display = 'block';
        jQuery('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Please help

Deepak

Comment: do form submission and then place e.preventDefault(); at end

Comment: no it did not work. I did jQuery("form").submit(); and then put e.preventDefault(); It works on chrome/FF/Opera but not on safari.

Comment: try this  jQuery('#edit-next').off('click');

Comment: that does not work in any browser, hide/show is never called.